# Runtime Version of ILMerge'd assembly is v4.0.20926; expected version is v4.0.30319

Tags: .net, ilmerge

This is what my .csproj AfterBuild looks like:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Exec Command="&quot;..\Tools\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe&quot; /internalize /ndebug /out:@(MainAssembly) /targetplatform:v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 &quot;@(IntermediateAssembly)&quot; @(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'&quot;%(FullPath)&quot;', ' ')" Condition=" '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.0'" />
  </Target>
```

I'm running 64-bit Windows.  I have tried changing the .NET Framework from `...\Microsoft.NET\Framework\...` to `...\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\...` but it didn't help.

I also created ILMerge.exe.config in the ILMerge directory:

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <requiredRuntime safemode="true" imageVersion="v4.0.30319" version="v4.0.30319"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Why isn't ILMerge generating a 4.0.30319 assembly?

Comment: What version of ilmerge are you using?

Comment: I tried the newer (since this question was asked) version released on 5/26, 2.10.0526, but I am still having the same problem.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in ILMerge which generates the runtime version of .Net 4.0 Beta2. I know this really doesn't help but you may contact Mike Barnett at Microsoft about it (his email is at the ILMerge download page)
Sorry

Comment: I contacted him a few days ago about this, so he's aware of it.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit: This problem is fixed in v2.11.0502 which was released on 2 May 2011 so I removed the download link for my custom version.**

I have fixed ILMerge.exe (v2.10.0526) so that it sets the target runtime version **v4.0.30319** and not **v4.0.20926**. You can download the fixed version of ILMerge.exe from this link:

(link removed, download the official version [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630))

Just run it with this parameter as usual

```
/targetplatform:v4,c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

and the output assembly will now target v4.0.30319. I have checked with Reflector and it's ok. Let me know your results.

Note that you don't need to use that ILMerge.exe.config, I guess it's for running ILMerge.exe itself with the .Net 4 framework, however this doesn't mean it will force ILMerge.exe to produce .Net 4 assemblies. Target framework version of the output assembly is only controlled with the **/targetplatform** parameter.

Comment: Hi tester, thank you! I'll try this out when I get the chance.

Comment: I copied the linked file down and can confirm that it does, indeed, set the output assembly correctly to v4.0.30319 where the MS download version was setting it to v4.0.20926.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem Here!!

I'm using ILMerge to target v4 with and without the /targetplatform:v4 and got the same result :.net runtime version targeting has greater .net v4 revision (as stated by reflector).

The base problem that took me to start digging was an error related to (Cannot load type System.Func´2 Exception from ) in a Linq and Lambda based code.

If I substitute the merged version with the non-merged version of the dependency assemblies no exception is thrown.

Comment: This is how I first noticed the problem, as well.